# Matrix reconstruction from sums

Tags: matrices

I want to reconstruct a matrix with all positive integer elements, given its row and column sums.

Is there an algorithm which will find all possible matrix element combinations, given the row and column sums.

Any reference is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess this boils down to partitioning positive integers, which is in general very difficult.

Comment: The entries are positive integers. Basically the environment would be like inputting the row and column sums and getting the output of all possible set of matrices which satisfy those sums.

Comment: @ ÍgjøgnumMeg No, the problem isn't difficult ! See the answer of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729456/reconstruct-a-matrix-from-its-row-and-column-sums)